# Updating and deleting java (red hat / centos) (closed)

Tags: linux, redhat, java

I am a total noob with linux. So please explain clearly if you have a solution for me.
I have an VPS and I want to update JAVA.
I found a guide on the Java site which says:

rpm -e < package_name >

I searched for the packages:

```
[root@srv1 ~]# rpm -qa | grep java 
java_cup-0.10k-5.el6.x86_64
java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0-29.1.el6.x86_64
```

Than I tried to do the delete command

[root@srv1 ~]# rpm -e java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0-29.1.el6.x86_64

error: Failed dependencies:

```
    java-gcj-compat is needed by (installed) java_cup-1:0.10k-5.el6.x86_64
    java-gcj-compat >= 1.0.70 is needed by (installed) sinjdoc-0.5-9.1.el6.x86_64
```

What should I do now? **Removing has worked thanks to the answer below**

**Problem two!**

Now am I installing this package from java

```
[root@srv1 java]# rpm -ivh jre-7u9-linux-i586.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:jre                    ########################################### [100%]
Unpacking JAR files...
        rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.7.0_09/lib/rt.pack
        jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.7.0_09/lib/jsse.pack
        charsets.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.7.0_09/lib/charsets.pack
        localedata.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.7.0_09/lib/ext/localedata.pack
        plugin.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.7.0_09/lib/plugin.pack
        javaws.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.7.0_09/lib/javaws.pack
        deploy.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.7.0_09/lib/deploy.pack
```

Can someone help me again with this?

Comment: The errors you see there are normal for that java distribution.

Comment: That means that it is ok now? But when I do java --version it gives an error that it can't create a virtual machine.

Comment: or should I reboot my server?

Comment: Also, where did you get that version of java?

Comment: http://www.java.com/nl/download/linux_manual.jsp , it's a dutch link. I took the first one.

Comment: Download the fourth link. You want the x64 (64-bit) version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's all you'll need to do...

`yum erase java-1.5.0-gcj` - That should take care of the dependencies...

If not, you can also remove the `java_cup` and `sinjdoc` packages as well.

From there, you should be able to install the java package you want per the instructions.

Comment: thank you, can you look to my second question to?

Comment: Java 1.7.09 installed Thank you very much!